# Equivalent Quantifier Free Formulas

Tags: z3

I want to know if Z3 can show equivalent formulas after Quantifier Elimination.

Example (exists k) (i x k) = 1 and k > 5
is equivalent to

i > 0 and 5 i - 1 < 0.

Here, quantifier k has been eliminated.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Kaustubh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Z3 can check whether two formulas are equivalent. To check whether `p` and `q` are equivalent. We must check whether `(not (iff p q))` is unsatisfiable.

Your example uses nonlinear arithmetic `i*k`. The quantifier elimination module in Z3 has limited support for nonlinear *real* arithmetic. It is based on virtual term substitution, which is not complete. However, it is sufficient for your example. 
We must enable the quantifier elimination module in Z3, and the nonlinear extensions (i.e., virtual term substitution).

Here is how we can encode your example in Z3: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/rXfi

Answer (score 1):

In general, the result of eliminating quantifiers can be obtained.  For instance by entering the following into [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3):

```
(declare-const i Real)
(assert (exists ((k Real)) (and (= (* i k) 1.0) (> k 5.0))))
(apply qe)
```

This case involves non-linear arithmetic, and Z3 does not eliminate the quantifier.

Comment: The support for nonlinear arithmetic is not enabled by default in the quantifier elimination module. That is why Z3 does not eliminate the quantifier in the script above. Here is the same example, with nonlinear support enabled: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/qrW1

Comment: I see, my mistake.  For reference, I tried using set-option, but that didn't work: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/vm7M.

Comment: Many thanks Josh and Leonardo. I have few more questions, I am asking them separately as a new thread.